Proof of $ \int_0^1 \frac{dx }{1+x^n}> \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}} ,\forall n=1,2,\cdots.$
This question is from AoPS Source, and I give a proof there as following:
Proof:
Use that result:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^n} \right)^n=\frac12.$$
You can refer Limit for a proof.
Let $$f(t)=\left(\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^t} \right)^t,\quad t\in[1,\infty),$$
then
$$f'(t) = \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx \right)^t \log \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx \right) -t \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx \right)^{t-1} \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{x^t \log x}{(1+x^t)^2} \, dx \right),\quad t\in(1,\infty).$$
If $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[1,\infty)$(we can compute that $f(1)>f(2)>f(3)$), then
$$\frac12=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^n} \right)^n=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N^+}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^n} \right)^n,$$ and
$$\left(\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^n}\right)^n>\frac12,\quad n=1,2,3,\cdots ,$$
i.e., $$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx }{1+x^n}>\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}},\quad n=1,2,3,\cdots.$$
(If there is some $N$ such that
$$\left(\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^N} \right)^N=\frac12,$$
then
$$\left(\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^n} \right)^n=\frac12,\quad\forall n\geq N,$$
which is impossible!)


In my proof, I should prove $f'(t)>0,\forall t\in(1,\infty)$.
Any hints and comments will welcom. Or someone can offer other menthod!


Thanks  @heropup  for pointing my mistake in computing $f'(t)$.

Have you tried power series approach ?

@
zeraoulia rafik Tahnk you, I will have a try!

We have
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^n}\,\mathrm{d} x
 &= 1 - \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1 + x^n}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &= 1 - \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + y}y^{1/n}\,\mathrm{d} y\\
 &\ge 1 - \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + y}[1 + (y - 1)/n]\,\mathrm{d} y\\
 &= 1 - \frac{\ln 2}{n} + \frac{2\ln 2 - 1}{n^2}
\end{align*}
where we use the substitution $y = x^n$ and the Bernoulli inequality $(1+z)^r \le 1 + zr$ for all $z \ge - 1$ and $0 < r \le 1$.
It suffices to prove that
$$1 - \frac{\ln 2}{n} + \frac{2\ln 2 - 1}{n^2} > \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}.$$
Letting $u := \frac{1}{n}$, it suffices to prove that, for all $u \in (0, 1]$,
$$1 - u\ln 2 + u^2(2\ln 2 - 1) > (1/2)^u$$
or (taking logarithm)
$$f(u) := \ln (1 - u\ln 2 + u^2(2\ln 2 - 1)) - u\ln \frac12 > 0.$$
We have
$$f'(u) = \frac{(2a^2 - a)u - a^2 + 4a - 2}{1 - ua + u^2(2a - 1)} \cdot u$$
where $a = \ln 2$.
Since $2a^2 - a > 0$ and $-a^2 + 4a - 2 > 0$, we have
$f'(u) > 0$ for all $u \in (0, 1]$. Also, $f(0) = 0$.
We have $f(u) > 0$ for all $u \in (0, 1]$.
We are done.

Thank you for you nice answer!  Could you give me some
suggestions for the monotonicity of the sequence $$\left{\left(\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^n} \right)^n\right}.$$ It "seems" strictly decreasing!

@Riemann Can we deal with $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^n},\mathrm{d} x
\ge \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^{n+1}},\mathrm{d} x\right)^{1+1/n}?$$

I don't konw, but this is a good idea, I will try. Thank you for your advice!

Can you provide more details why the last inequality is true?

@RFZ I edited the answer.

I don't think your calculation of $f'(t)$ is correct.  If $$f(t) = \left(\int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx \right)^t,$$ then $$\log f(t) = t \log \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx \right)$$
hence
$$\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} = \log \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx \right) + \frac{t}{\int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx} \left(-\int_{x=0}^1 \frac{x^t \log x}{(1+x^t)^2} \, dx \right) ,$$
and
$$f'(t) = \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx \right)^t \log \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx \right) -t \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^t} \, dx \right)^{t-1} \left( \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{x^t \log x}{(1+x^t)^2} \, dx \right).$$

Thank you for pointinf out! I  will fix it.

It seems that proving that $f(t)=\Big(\int^1_0 \frac{1}{1+x^t}\,dt\Big)^t$
is not as easy as it seems. One can however try a more direct approach. Here I present one solution that uses:

Integration by parts.
The fact that for $0<y<1$, $y^\beta<y^\alpha$ for all $0<\alpha<\beta$.
the inequality $e^{-t}<1-t+\frac{t^2}{2}$ for all $t>0$.

\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{1}{1+x^n}\,dx&=1-\int^1_0\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx\stackrel{y=x^n}=1-\frac1n\int^1_0 \frac{y^{1/n}}{1+y}\,dy\\
&=1-\frac1n\int^1_0 y^{1/n} \,d(\log(1+y))\\
&\stackrel{IBP}{=}1-\frac{\log 2}{n}+\frac1{n^2}\int^1_0\log(1+y)\, y^{1-\tfrac1n}\,dy\\
&> 1-\frac{\log 2}{n}+\frac1{n^2}\int^1_0\log(1+y)\, y\,dy\\
&= 1-\frac{\log 2}{n}+\frac1{4n^2}\\
&>1-\frac{\log 2}{n}+\frac{\log^22}{2n^2}>e^{-\tfrac{\log2}{n}}=2^{-\tfrac1n}
\end{align}

Thank you for your nice answer and comment!

Some thoughts about the monotonicity.
We want to prove that, for all $n\ge 4$
$$\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^n}\,\mathrm{d} x\right)^n
\ge \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d} x\right)^{n+1}. \tag{1}$$
(Note: The case $n=1, 2, 3$ is easy.)
Discussion.
By Bernoulli inequality $(1+z)^r \le 1 + zr$ for all $z \ge -1$ and $0 < r \le 1$, it suffices to prove that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^n}\,\mathrm{d} x
\ge \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d} x\right)\cdot 
\left[1 + \frac{1}{n}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d} x - 1\right)\right],$$
or
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^n}\,\mathrm{d} x
\ge (1 - 1/n)\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d} x
+ \frac{1}{n}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d} x\right)^2. \tag{2}$$
We have
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^n}\,\mathrm{d} x
= \frac{1}{2n} \left[\psi\left(\frac{1/n + 1}{2}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)\right] \tag{3}$$
where $\psi(\cdot)$ is the digamma function defined by $\psi(u) = \frac{\mathrm{d} \ln \Gamma(u)}{\mathrm{d} u} = \frac{\Gamma'(u)}{\Gamma(u)}$.
From (3), it seems that (via Maple)
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^n}\,\mathrm{d} x
= 1 - \frac{\ln 2}{n} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k \zeta(k) (1 - 2^{1-k})\cdot \frac{1}{n^k}. \tag{4}$$
From (4), it seems that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^n}\,\mathrm{d} x
\ge 1 - \frac{\ln 2}{n} + \sum_{k=2}^7 (-1)^k \zeta(k) (1 - 2^{1-k})\cdot \frac{1}{n^k}, \tag{5}$$
and
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d} x
\le 1 - \frac{\ln 2}{n+1} + \sum_{k=2}^6 (-1)^k \zeta(k) (1 - 2^{1-k})\cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^k}. \tag{6}$$
If (5) and (6) is true (how to prove?), then (2) is true.
